# How can I format the way Apache logs an error?

Tags: php, apache

So this is a sample line of what i get:

```
[Wed Dec 03 13:18:04.922126 2014] [:error] [pid 5328:tid 812] [client 172.16.0.28:55434] <<<error/warning message>>>>, referer: http://mydomain.iosif/messages
```

And I would need something like this:

```
[Dec 03 13:18:04] <<<error/warning message>>>>
```

Just for easy debuging

Comment: make a regular expression match and only display the info needed.

Comment: I'm not that good at regular expressions, but still I needed a different log, not a different way of displaying it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set log format in your VirtualHost [Piped Logs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/logs.html#piped), [ErrorLogFormat Directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#errorlogformat).
Or use [sscanf](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sscanf.php) function to parse logs

Comment: I saw the ErrorLogFormat Directive but i missed the fact that I had to add it to VirtualHost